# Access to system variable by using os.environ

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created `Windows system variable` using below code:

```
import os
os.environ['BJT'] = 'HELLO'
```

But I can't see it in `Advanced settings \  system variables`  Also I can't see it when I try to print it:

```
import os
print(os.environ['BJT'])
```

I thought that when I create system variable using os.environ it is created exacly like when I do it in system settings. Is it possible to create system variable from python code and access it even when I restart computer?

Comment: That variable will only be available in that python process session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the system (with admin privileges) to create a [system variable](https://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/), you can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['setx', 'BJT', '"HELLO"', '/M'])
```

Prior to **python3.5** you will need to use `process.call` instead

Answer (score 1):

There is a misunderstanding with what environment is. It is just a mapping of (string) variables that a process can pass to its children. Specifically a process can change its own environment (which will be used by its future children) but this will not change its parent's environment, nor even the environment of its already existing children if any.

In addition, Windows provides system and user environment variables which are used as the initial environment of any process. This are not changet by `os.environ` nor by `putenv` but only from the Windows API or the shell command `setx`.